# PDF file formation using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I use the following code to display a line in a PDF file using iText:

```
Phrase phraseHeader = new Phrase(18, new Chunk("Registration Form       "+registrationForm.getRegistrationDate(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD)));
Paragraph paragraph=new Paragraph(phraseHeader);
paragraph.setAlignment("center");
document.add(paragraph);
```

If I run this code the pdf file will contain the following:

```
Registration Form        26-Apr-2013 11:58:20
```

I want to display the "Registration Form" in a larger font and the date/time in a smaller font, but both should be in the same line. How can I am do this?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
    Phrase phraseHeader  = new Phrase();
    phraseHeader.add(
            new Chunk("Registration Form        ",
                    FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD)));
    phraseHeader.add(
            new Chunk(registrationForm.getRegistrationDate(),
                    FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD)));

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(phraseHeader);
```

Comment: @user2007374 If Xavier's code works for you, please accept it as the correct answer (using the link left of the message).